# Connected Dot - unManaged package deployment

Tags: deployment, eclipse, unmanaged-package

Connected Dots is a unmanaged package from Salesforce. I have modified one of the components in the package in fullcopy. Wanted to deploy.

I tried deploying with Eclipse, it is giving timeout error **'Server processing time is exceeded limit (600sec)'** after 10 mins.

I just created the project in Eclipse, loaded the project with components from Connected Dots package.
After that, trying to sync it with production server. It is displaying all the components on deployment mini page. I selecting only one component for overriding that I have modified.

Not sure why it is happening like this.

Any suggestions or different tools to deploy the unmanaged package to production ?

Comment: Do you have this package installed in production? Do this first and then deploy only modified code from the sandbox. Make sure you created/tweaked test code also to get at least 75% coverage.

Comment: @Oleksiy, I don't see any test apex test class inside the Unmanaged package.. Test classes, would it be  inside the package or outside the package ?.. Yes, package is already in production.  Can I use the change set to move this modified component to Production ?.. Using Eclipse, I can run only specify required Test classed to run ?

Comment: Depending when this app was developed, test code could reside inside of Apex classes. Try to edit code in sandbox and them deploy to Production by using Change Sets.